# Is it possible to input to a const double array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const double* constArr = new const double [];
for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
cin >>constArr[i];
```

Something like that? Is it possible to input to a const double array?

Comment: OT: `c++` is case sensitive. Not sure why you capitalized the first letter of each line.

Comment: Did you try it? What do you think `const` should mean?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Unless you create it as `double[]` first, assign some numbers, and then assign the pointer to `const double *`.

Comment: Try `std::vector` instead. But beware that it can't contain `const` elements.

Comment: Operator `new` and operator `new []` are for library writers. Don't use them. For an array that can be resized, use std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to use a factory function that adds the elements to a non-const container and then move that into a constant container. You shouldn't be using raw owning pointers, so I would change that to a `unique_ptr` which will allow you to do the same things more or less with the added benefit of automatically deleting the array when the pointer is destroyed.

```
std::unique_ptr<double[]> create_my_array(size_t n) {
    auto my_array = std::make_unique<double[]>(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> my_array[i];
    return my_array;
}
```

Then you can do

```
 std::unique_ptr<const double[]> const_array = create_my_array(n);
```

You can do something very similar with a function using `new double[]`, returning the pointer and the callee storing it into a `const double *`, but that approach achieves nothing more and is prone to leaking memory.

If you do not want to use a function at all, eg because this functionality is only required once in your whole program, you can use the same idea with a scoped `unique_ptr<double>` which is then moved into the const version.

```
std::unique_ptr<const double[]> const_array;
{  // Enclosing this in a block makes the non const pointer unavailable after we've filled it
    auto my_array = std::make_unique<double[]>(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cin >> my_array[i];
    const_array = std::move(my_array);
}
```

Comment: Or you could use an anonymous inline function, something like `const auto v = ([&] { std::vector<double> result; for (int i : boost::irange(0, n)) { double x; std::cin >> x; result.push_back(x); }; return result; }) ();`

Comment: Thanks you very much!